# Firemonkey Text selection on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, textselection

I created a form with a syntax highlighter which draws over the `TForm.OnPaint` event. On Windows I can simply use Form events to "simulate" the native Windows text selections.

Is it possible to implement the native text selection on android with this setup? I cant find any documentaries for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by native text selection? you mean using the java EditView ?